# Search by date, category and tag with Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder, symfony-3.4

I'm finally working on a project in Symfony 3 and it's really very interesting.

I work on a search form for publications according to several criteria (I have 3 fields input text: date, category and tag).

So I handle publication consisting of a date, linked to a category by a relationship oneToMany [Publication is the entity owner, each publication to a single category] and having several several Tag [there is a relationship ManyToMany with the Tag entity. Finally I managed to create the form and find the publication by and by category but I want to search by date, category and tag I encountered an error that I could solve it.

Repository request:

```
   public function findEnglishByTags($date, $categorie, $tag) {

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('english');
    $qb->Where('english.date = :date')
            ->andWhere('english.Categorie = :categorie')
            ->leftjoin('english.tags', 't')
            ->where('english.tags = :t.id')
            ->setParameters(array('date' => $date, 'categorie' => $categorie, 'tags' => $tag))
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

my controller  function:

```
 public function searchAction() {
    $form = $this->createForm('MDWEB\FrontBundle\Form\InEnglishFrontType');
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $date = $form->get('date')->getData();
    $categorie = $form->get('categorie')->getData();
    $tag = $form->get('tags')->getData();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $listEnglishs = $em->getRepository('MDWEBInEnglishBundle:InEnglish')->findEnglishBytags(new \DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d')), $categorie, $tag);
    var_dump($listEnglishs);
    return $this->render('MDWEBFrontBundle:InEnglish:list.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'listEnglishs' => $listEnglishs
    ));
}
```

This is the mistake I've encountered:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MPtS.png)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Also, please make sure that you attach any errors/logs in form of text, not screenshot...

Comment: @user10269341: `Syntax error` usually would mean that your DQL could not be "compiled" into SQL. Please attach the output of `$queryBuilder->getDQL()` before `getResult()` the query...

Answer (score 2):

Can you try please :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('english');
      ->select('english')
      ->leftJoin('english.tags', 't')
      ->where('english.date = :date')
      ->andWhere('english.Categorie = :categorie')
      ->andWhere('english.tags = :tags')
      ->setParameters([
           'date'       => $date,
           'categorie'  => $categorie,
           'tags'       => $tag
      ])
```

Seems in setParameters you try to set `tags` but in the query you try to do `english.tags = :t.id`. Be sure that `date` is a datetime. $tag & $categorie are instants of Categorie & Tag.

Comment: This makes much sense, but wasn't there more verbose message in such case?

Comment: I agree with you @JovanPerovic this is one problem

Comment: thank you for your answer but this code also supports a syntax error concerning the tag

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the collaboration of each member the people who give me help,
finally I found the solution, I wanted to share it with you, maybe someone else needs it.

```
 public function findEnglishByTags($date, $categorie, $tags) {
    $tags_values = $tags->getValues();
    array_walk($tags_values, function (&$item) {
        $item = $item->getId();
    });


    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('english');
    $qb->where('english.date = :date')
            ->andWhere('english.Categorie IN (:categories)')
            ->leftjoin('english.tags', 't')
            ->andWhere('t.id IN (:tags)')
            ->setParameters(array('date' => $date, 'categories' => $categorie->getId(), 'tags' => $tags))
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```